Quarkus Dev Services on MacOS: attempts to find a Docker environment failed
Describe the problem
I want to use Postgresql as my Dev Service database. On my MacOS I have both docker (via Rancher Desktop) as well as podman installed. When starting my quarkus app in the dev profile, it crashes and complains that no Docker environment could be found?
My environment
~ podman --version
podman version 5.1.2

~ docker --version
Docker version 25.0.4-rd, build c4cd0a9

~ which docker
/Users/XXXX/.rd/bin/docker

~ which podman
/opt/homebrew/bin/podman

My application.properties file
# Dev Services
quarkus.datasource.devservices.enabled = true

# Datasource configuration
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.username=XXXX
quarkus.datasource.password=XXXX

# Reactive datasource configuration
%dev.quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=vertx-reactive:postgresql://localhost:5433/quarkus

# Hibernate ORM configuration
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create
quarkus.hibernate-orm.sql-load-script=import.sql

Expected behavior
A new postgresql container spins up managed by quarkus with the default quarkus database and quarkus user preconfigured as described here
Detailed error
~ quarkus dev    
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< com.example:dev-backend >-----------------------
[INFO] Building dev-backend 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive:jar:3.11.3 has been relocated to io.quarkus:quarkus-rest:jar:3.11.3: Update the artifactId in your project build file. Refer to https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guide-3.9 for more information.
[WARNING] The artifact io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson:jar:3.11.3 has been relocated to io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-jackson:jar:3.11.3: Update the artifactId in your project build file. Refer to https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guide-3.9 for more information.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus:3.11.3:dev (default-cli) @ dev-backend ---
[INFO] Invoking resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ dev-backend
[INFO] Copying 3 resources from src/main/resources to target/classes
[INFO] Invoking quarkus:3.11.3:generate-code (default) @ dev-backend
[INFO] Invoking compiler:3.12.1:compile (default-compile) @ dev-backend
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date.
[INFO] Invoking resources:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ dev-backend
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory XXXX
[INFO] Invoking quarkus:3.11.3:generate-code-tests (default) @ dev-backend
[INFO] Invoking compiler:3.12.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ dev-backend
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date.
[WARNING] Changed debug port to 58259 because of a port conflict
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 58259
11:02:18 INFO  [or.te.do.DockerMachineClientProviderStrategy] (build-55) docker-machine executable was not found on PATH (XXXX)
11:02:18 ERROR [or.te.do.DockerClientProviderStrategy] (build-55) Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration. Attempted configurations were:
        EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception NullPointerException (Cannot invoke "String.hashCode()" because "<local5>" is null)
        UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (Could not find unix domain socket). Root cause NoSuchFileException (/var/run/docker.sock)
        DockerDesktopClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception NullPointerException (Cannot invoke "java.nio.file.Path.toString()" because the return value of "org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerDesktopClientProviderStrategy.getSocketPath()" is null)As no valid configuration was found, execution cannot continue.
See https://java.testcontainers.org/on_failure.html for more details.

11:02:18 WARN  [io.qu.de.IsDockerWorking] (build-55) Unable to parse DOCKER_HOST URI /Users/XXXX/.rd/bin/docker, it will be ignored for working Docker detection
11:02:18 WARN  [io.qu.de.ut.ContainerRuntimeUtil] (build-55) Command "docker info" exited with error code 1. Rootless container runtime detection might not be reliable or the container service is not running at all.
11:02:18 INFO  [or.te.im.PullPolicy] (build-55) Image pull policy will be performed by: DefaultPullPolicy()
11:02:18 INFO  [or.te.ut.ImageNameSubstitutor] (build-55) Image name substitution will be performed by: DefaultImageNameSubstitutor (composite of 'ConfigurationFileImageNameSubstitutor' and 'PrefixingImageNameSubstitutor')
2024-08-06 11:02:18,644 INFO  [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Attempting to start live reload endpoint to recover from previous Quarkus startup failure
2024-08-06 11:02:18,816 ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor#launchDatabases threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Previous attempts to find a Docker environment failed. Will not retry. Please see logs and check configuration
        at io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.startDevDb(DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.java:363)
        at io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.launchDatabases(DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.java:142)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.doRunWith(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2516)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2495)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:483)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Previous attempts to find a Docker environment failed. Will not retry. Please see logs and check configuration
        at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.getFirstValidStrategy(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:232)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.getOrInitializeStrategy(DockerClientFactory.java:152)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:194)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory$1.getDockerClient(DockerClientFactory.java:106)
        at com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClientDelegate.authConfig(DockerClientDelegate.java:109)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:329)
        at io.quarkus.devservices.postgresql.deployment.PostgresqlDevServicesProcessor$1.startDatabase(PostgresqlDevServicesProcessor.java:80)
        at io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.startDevDb(DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.java:289)
        ... 11 more

        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:331)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:252)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:58)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:113)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:435)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:56)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:138)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:93)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:131)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:62)
Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor#launchDatabases threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Previous attempts to find a Docker environment failed. Will not retry. Please see logs and check configuration
        at io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.startDevDb(DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.java:363)
        at io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.launchDatabases(DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.java:142)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.doRunWith(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2516)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2495)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:483)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Previous attempts to find a Docker environment failed. Will not retry. Please see logs and check configuration
        at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.getFirstValidStrategy(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:232)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.getOrInitializeStrategy(DockerClientFactory.java:152)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:194)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory$1.getDockerClient(DockerClientFactory.java:106)
        at com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClientDelegate.authConfig(DockerClientDelegate.java:109)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:329)
        at io.quarkus.devservices.postgresql.deployment.PostgresqlDevServicesProcessor$1.startDatabase(PostgresqlDevServicesProcessor.java:80)
        at io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.startDevDb(DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.java:289)
        ... 11 more

        at io.quarkus.builder.Execution.run(Execution.java:123)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildExecutionBuilder.execute(BuildExecutionBuilder.java:79)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:160)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:327)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Previous attempts to find a Docker environment failed. Will not retry. Please see logs and check configuration
        at io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.startDevDb(DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.java:363)
        at io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.launchDatabases(DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.java:142)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.doRunWith(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2516)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2495)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:483)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Previous attempts to find a Docker environment failed. Will not retry. Please see logs and check configuration
        at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.getFirstValidStrategy(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:232)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.getOrInitializeStrategy(DockerClientFactory.java:152)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:194)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory$1.getDockerClient(DockerClientFactory.java:106)
    com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClientDelegate.authConfig(DockerClientDelegate.java:109)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:329)
        at io.quarkus.devservices.postgresql.deployment.PostgresqlDevServicesProcessor$1.startDatabase(PostgresqlDevServicesProcessor.java:80)
        at io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.startDevDb(DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.java:289)
        ... 11 more

